# UISearchcontroller Cancel button delegate

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller

There is a cancel button when you use a `UISearchcontroller`.

I want to make something happen when I press the cancel button.

Is there any Function or Delegate that trigger when the cancel button is clicked?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
}
```